# How to play .aac format audio file in android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

How to play .aac audio format in android.

I tried using ffmpeg convert audio format and play in android-ndk. But im not able to implement.

Please let me know any ideas or any ref link to follow

Answer (score 0):

You can check this native aac player implementation. It is ffmpeg-based, and I heard it is fairly light on CPU.

http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/

Comment: It doesn't support pause/resume functionality.